# Multiple async dispatches on page load gives error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my homepage, I've got several widgets that need to return data from async operations. In each component, I am dispatching the action as such:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(homepageActions.getUpcomingTrips());
}
```

I receive a `TypeError: data.upcoming_hikes is undefined` error when I hook up a second widget in the same way however. Upon review of my state, it appears that my data is being "overwritten" because these are all being called at the same time.

Looking at the Redux devtools, I can see HOMEPAGE_CURRENT_PACK_REQUEST, HOMEPAGE_UPCOMING_TRIPS_REQUEST, HOMEPAGE_UPCOMING_TRIPS_SUCCESS, and HOMEPAGE_CURRENT_PACK_REQUEST in that order. And my data looks like this:

HOMEPAGE_UPCOMING_TRIPS_SUCCESS:
[image]

HOMEPAGE_CURRENT_PACK_SUCCESS:
[image]

It seems to me like the data object is being overwritten?

My reducer is written as such:

```
import { homepageConstants } from '../_constants';

const initialState = {
  data: {},
  loading: true,
  error: null,
}

export function homepage(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log('action: ', action);

    // current pack widget reducer
    switch (action.type) {
        case homepageConstants.CURRENT_PACK_REQUEST:
            return {
        ...state,
                data   : {},
                loading: true,
            };
        case homepageConstants.CURRENT_PACK_SUCCESS:
            return {
        ...state,
                data   : action.data,
                loading: false,
            };
        case homepageConstants.CURRENT_PACK_FAILURE:
            return {
        ...state,
                error: action.error,
            };

        // total miles widget reducer
        case homepageConstants.TOTAL_MILES_REQUEST:
            return {
        ...state,
                data   : {},
                loading: true,
            };
        case homepageConstants.TOTAL_MILES_SUCCESS:
            return {
        ...state,
                data   : action.data,
                loading: false,
            };
        case homepageConstants.TOTAL_MILES_FAILURE:
            return {
        ...state,
                error: action.error,
            };

        // upcoming trips widget reducer
        case homepageConstants.UPCOMING_TRIPS_REQUEST:
            return {
        ...state,
                data: {},
                loading: true,
            };
        case homepageConstants.UPCOMING_TRIPS_SUCCESS:
            return {
        ...state,
                data: action.data,
                loading: false,
            };
        case homepageConstants.UPCOMING_TRIPS_FAILURE:
            return {
        ...state,
                error: action.error,
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

If my guess is correct in that data is being overwritten (because that's the name of that key inside every reducer case, how should I handle this? Is there a better way to handle multiple dispatches like this on page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

1. To spread the `action.data`. In this approach you have to modify how you will be accessing the elements.

```js
{
  ...state,
  ...action.data,
}
```

2. To spread both `data` and `action.data` and store in `data`.

```
{
  ...state,
  data: {
    ...state.data,
    ...action.data,
  },
}
```

Either of these two will solve your problem,

Comment: Brilliant! Looks like I need to brush up on my ES6 and spread operators now.

Comment: Spread operator is more powerful than what it seems like on the surface. We can do a lot of things with the spread operator. Here is a link to start “7 Tricks with Resting and Spreading JavaScript Objects” by Joel Thoms https://link.medium.com/9q07xaYReV